# Better way to assign free system memory to a variable within R?

Tags: r, linux, memory

I've got a script that is memory intensive, and I don't want it to run unless there is a big free chunk.  So I wrote this:

```
library(dplyr)
system("free | tee free.txt")
memfree <-   read.delim("free.txt")[1,] %>% as.character %>% 
  strsplit(" ") %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  (function(x){x[length(x)]}) %>% 
  as.numeric/1e6
system("rm free.txt")
```

I get a `memfree` variable, and I can use it as a condition.

But there has got to be a better way, that doesn't involve saving cruft to disk and then reading it again, and doing weird string parsing.  What is it?

Comment: you want to know how much memory is free? can use the internet argument of system? FYI you can replace x[length(x)] with tail(1)

Comment: Oh good point re `tail` but yeah I don't just want to print it to screen, I want to put it in a variable

Comment: aha! `intern = T` is what you meant, but you got auto-corrected.

Comment: oh! confusing auto correct indeed 

Answer (score 0):

One solution is

```
freemem <- function(){
    tmp <- system("free", inter=TRUE)[2]
    tmp <- gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", tmp, perl=TRUE)
    as.numeric(strsplit(tmp, " ")[[1]][4])/1e6
}
freemem()
```

In my output of `system("free")` the free memory is shown in the fourth column, not the last.